# os x document types without becoming default app

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, document

I have numerous CFBundleTypeExtensions listed as Document types in my project, and it works fine allowing my app to open files with these extensions.  But in some cases it seems to become the default app for these files on certain user's machines which I never intended to happen.  Anyone know how to solve this issue?

rc

Comment: I'm guessing this happens if there is no other app on the machine that is associated with that extension, yes?

Comment: Supposedly not according to users that have reported it to me. But I cannot recreate this myself...

Comment: Any other ideas about this? Thanks!